# JPA query works in postgres but retuns some null fields in API

Tags: sql, postgresql, spring-boot, jpa

I have defined this function in my repository , it works fine in my database as I tested it and all the fields contains values.

```
@Query(value="SELECT employee_id,\n" +
            "SUM(january) as january,SUM(february) as february, SUM(march) as march, SUM(april) as april, SUM(may) as may, SUM(june) as june, SUM(july) as july, SUM(august) as august, sum(september) as septebmer, sum(october) as october, sum(november)as november\n" +
            "from\n" +
            "(\n" +
            "SELECT * FROM\n" +
            "(SELECT t1.id as task_id,\n" +
            "       count(CASE WHEN extract(isodow from dt) BETWEEN 1 AND 5 AND EXTRACT(MONTH from dt) = 1 THEN 1 END) as january,\n" +
            "       count(CASE WHEN extract(isodow from dt) BETWEEN 1 AND 5 AND EXTRACT(MONTH from dt) = 2 THEN 1 END) as february,\n" +
            "       count(CASE WHEN extract(isodow from dt) BETWEEN 1 AND 5 AND EXTRACT(MONTH from dt) = 3 THEN 1 END) as march,\n" +
            "\t   count(CASE WHEN extract(isodow from dt) BETWEEN 1 AND 5 AND EXTRACT(MONTH from dt) = 4 THEN 1 END) as april,\n" +
            "       count(CASE WHEN extract(isodow from dt) BETWEEN 1 AND 5 AND EXTRACT(MONTH from dt) = 5 THEN 1 END) as may,\n" +
            "       count(CASE WHEN extract(isodow from dt) BETWEEN 1 AND 5 AND EXTRACT(MONTH from dt) = 6 THEN 1 END) as june,\n" +
            "       count(CASE WHEN extract(isodow from dt) BETWEEN 1 AND 5 AND EXTRACT(MONTH from dt) = 7 THEN 1 END) as july,\n" +
            "       count(CASE WHEN extract(isodow from dt) BETWEEN 1 AND 5 AND EXTRACT(MONTH from dt) = 8 THEN 1 END) as august,\n" +
            "       count(CASE WHEN extract(isodow from dt) BETWEEN 1 AND 5 AND EXTRACT(MONTH from dt) = 9 THEN 1 END) as september,\n" +
            "       count(CASE WHEN extract(isodow from dt) BETWEEN 1 AND 5 AND EXTRACT(MONTH from dt) = 10 THEN 1 END) as october,\n" +
            "\t   count(CASE WHEN extract(isodow from dt) BETWEEN 1 AND 5 AND EXTRACT(MONTH from dt) = 11 THEN 1 END) as november,\n" +
            "       count(CASE WHEN extract(isodow from dt) BETWEEN 1 AND 5 AND EXTRACT(MONTH from dt) = 12 THEN 1 END) as december\n" +
            "FROM task as t1\n" +
            "CROSS JOIN generate_series(t1.start_date,t1.end_date,cast('1 day' as interval)) dt\n" +
            "group by t1.id)\n" +
            "as days\n" +
            "INNER JOIN \n" +
            "(SELECT result2.task_id,client_id, employee_id, employee.username from\n" +
            "(SELECT result.task_id, task_name, task_start_date, result.task_end_date,project_id,project_name,client_id, employee_id FROM\n" +
            "(SELECT task.id as task_id, task.name as task_name, task.start_date as task_start_date, task.end_date as task_end_date, project.id as project_id,  \n" +
            "project.name as project_name , project.client_id\n" +
            "FROM project,task\n" +
            "WHERE project.id=task.project_id)\n" +
            "as result, employee_task\n" +
            "WHERE employee_task.task_id=result.task_id\n" +
            "AND client_id= :client_id)\n" +
            "as result2, employee\n" +
            "WHERE employee.id=result2.employee_id)\n" +
            "as info\n" +
            "ON days.task_id=info.task_id)\n" +
            "as final_table\n" +
            "GROUP BY employee_id",nativeQuery = true)
    List<WorkdaysRepartition> getWorkDaysPerClient(@Param("client_id")long client_id);
```

however when i try to return the result via a controller, it returns some null fields ( december and september )

```
this is the result in my database : 
   id   jan feb ................................december
    14  21  20  23  22  22  22  21  23  22  21  22
    15  21  20  1   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0
    16  21  20  23  21  5   22  21  23  22  21  22
    17  21  20  1   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0
    18  10  0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0
    19  21  20  23  21  22  22  21  23  22  21  22
    20  0   0   23  21  22  22  21  23  22  0   0
    21  0   0   0   21  22  22  21  23  22  21  22
    22  0   0   23  21  22  22  21  23  22  21  22
    23  0   0   23  21  22  22  21  23  22  21  22
```

this is the response JSON in POSTMAN  :

```
[
    {
        "december": null,
        "september": null,
        "october": 21,
        "november": 22,
        "june": 22,
        "august": 23,
        "july": 21,
        "january": 21,
        "april": 22,
        "may": 22,
        "february": 20,
        "march": 23,
        "employee_id": 14
    },
    {
        "december": null,
        "september": null,
        "october": 0,
        "november": 0,
        "june": 0,
        "august": 0,
        "july": 0,
        "january": 21,
        "april": 0,
        "may": 0,
        "february": 20,
        "march": 1,
        "employee_id": 15
    },
    {
        "december": null,
        "september": null,
        "october": 21,
        "november": 22,
        "june": 22,
        "august": 23,
        "july": 21,
        "january": 21,
        "april": 21,
        "may": 5,
        "february": 20,
        "march": 23,
        "employee_id": 16
    },
    {
        "december": null,
        "september": null,
        "october": 0,
        "november": 0,
        "june": 0,
        "august": 0,
        "july": 0,
        "january": 21,
        "april": 0,
        "may": 0,
        "february": 20,
        "march": 1,
        "employee_id": 17
    },
    {
        "december": null,
        "september": null,
        "october": 0,
        "november": 0,
        "june": 0,
        "august": 0,
        "july": 0,
        "january": 10,
        "april": 0,
        "may": 0,
        "february": 0,
        "march": 0,
        "employee_id": 18
    },
    {
        "december": null,
        "september": null,
        "october": 21,
        "november": 22,
        "june": 22,
        "august": 23,
        "july": 21,
        "january": 21,
        "april": 21,
        "may": 22,
        "february": 20,
        "march": 23,
        "employee_id": 19
    },
    {
        "december": null,
        "september": null,
        "october": 0,
        "november": 0,
        "june": 22,
        "august": 23,
        "july": 21,
        "january": 0,
        "april": 21,
        "may": 22,
        "february": 0,
        "march": 23,
        "employee_id": 20
    },
    {
        "december": null,
        "september": null,
        "october": 21,
        "november": 22,
        "june": 22,
        "august": 23,
        "july": 21,
        "january": 0,
        "april": 21,
        "may": 22,
        "february": 0,
        "march": 0,
        "employee_id": 21
    },
    {
        "december": null,
        "september": null,
        "october": 21,
        "november": 22,
        "june": 22,
        "august": 23,
        "july": 21,
        "january": 0,
        "april": 21,
        "may": 22,
        "february": 0,
        "march": 23,
        "employee_id": 22
    },
    {
        "december": null,
        "september": null,
        "october": 21,
        "november": 22,
        "june": 22,
        "august": 23,
        "july": 21,
        "january": 0,
        "april": 21,
        "may": 22,
        "february": 0,
        "march": 23,
        "employee_id": 23
    }
]
```

and finally : this is my WorkdaysRepartition interface

```
public interface WorkdaysRepartition {
    Long getEmployee_id();
    Long getJanuary();
    Long getFebruary();
    Long getMarch();
    Long getApril();
    Long getMay();
    Long getJune();
    Long getJuly();
    Long getAugust();
    Long getSeptember();
    Long getOctober();
    Long getNovember();
    Long getDecember();
}
```

any solutions?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. you have a typo in as septebmer
2. the December is missing at all